# jedi-vim return to old position after jump with goto assignments/definitions

Tags: vim, jedi-vim

I'm using vim with `jedi`/`jedi-vim` when I develop python code and I use extensively `<Leader>d` (goto definitions) and/or `<Leader>g` (goto assignments). I can use `''` to return to the line before the jump, but only within the same file.

Is there a way to have the same behaviour when jumping between different files?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> all the time to jump back (not only for Jedi, but also).

Also with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> you can do the opposite: Jump forward.

Comment: That's control-oh and control-eye in case the font is unclear.